# RavenDB -- More Like This -- Need a (similarity) metric; not just rank-orders

Tags: ravendb, similarity, tf-idf, morelikethis

I have a RavenDB / 'More Like This' example running (C#) as per 
[Creating more like this in RavenDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428215/creating-more-like-this-in-ravendb)

However, in addition to receiving similar documents back, I really need some measure of similarity back for those documents.

I am assuming (correctly?) that the order in which I get the similar documents back represents the rank-order scores of the documents' similarities (first one back has the highest similarity, second one back has the second highest similarity, etc.).

However, rather than rank orders I need the metric similarity results. This assumes (of course) that the rank orders are computed from a more continuous metric; e.g., tf-idf. If that is true, can I get a hold of those metric scores?

Answer (score 0):

When using `MoreLikeThis`, you can issue a query such as the following:

```
from index 'Product/Search'
where morelikethis(id() = 'products/1-A')
```

And assuming you have setup the `TermVector` on the index properly, you'll get the results.
In the metadata of the results, you have the index score, which is what I think you are looking for.

[image]